# UIWebview & JS effects - navigation bar caching

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios, uiwebview, uinavigationbar

I implemented UIWebview with navigation bar and any new visited page will be added to the navigation stack but the problem is when I hide some element before pushing the new view and go back to the same page the element stays hidden even if I show it again

Here is My JS code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                           $('#hello').fadeIn('slow');}); 
    $('.facebook,.location, .mainItem').hide();         
    $('.facebook,.location, .mainItem').show();

    $('.contactIcon').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
         $('.facebook,.location, .mainItem').fadeOut('slow', function() {
         window.location = "contact.html"; 
         });
     });
```

and here is the Objective-C Code

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{
DrillDownWebExampleAppDelegate *appDelegate = 
(DrillDownWebExampleAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

if(navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeOther)
{
    NSURL *url2 = [request URL];
    NSString *URLStr = [url2 absoluteString];

    RootViewController* viewController = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
    NSString *holder = [self getQueryStringInner:URLStr];
    [self getQueryString:URLStr];
    if([holder length] != 0 )
    {
        appDelegate.title =@"Title"; 
        appDelegate.query = queryString;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
        [viewController release];
        return NO;
    }



}
return YES;
}
```

Can you please help with that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a small trick but I think there is another way

I showed the elements again after window.location

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                       $('#hello').fadeIn('slow');}); 
$('.facebook,.location, .mainItem').hide();         
$('.facebook,.location, .mainItem').show();

$('.contactIcon').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
     $('.facebook,.location, .mainItem').fadeOut('slow', function() {
     window.location = "contact.html"; 
     $('.facebook,.location, .mainItem').show();
     });
 });
```

It works like this